Does NHST in statistics fit oft-used reasoning patterns?
Using Null Hypothesis Significance Testing (NHST), not rejecting  the null hypothesis is never equivalent to accepting the null hypothesis.
But, to everyday reasoning, failing to reject a hypothesis under some condition is tantamount to accepting the proposition (with a certain level of certainty).
For example, consider the hypothesis that a person is infected with a certain virus (e.g.SARS-CoV-2 ), and that the virus is active. If we perform tests that are powerful enough, then our lack of ability to find the traces of the virus will lead us to the conclusion that the person is most likely not infected with that virus.
Doesn't the fact that not rejecting the null hypothesis is never considered as evidence for the null hypothesis, shows that there is something in NHST that contradicts our reasoning patterns?

Not rejecting the null is typically not considered enough to accept it in NHST because those tests are designed to reject the null. If the tests are "powerful enough" for acceptance of a hypothesis then it should not be designated as the null in the first place. Compare to trials where innocence is the null and evidence is selected to reject it (prove guilt). As a result, not guilty is too weak to prove innocence, that requires inspecting a different selection of evidence. It could happen that what is presented at trial is enough even for that, but it is not designed to deliver it.

You are correct. Significance testing is actually based on an outright fallacy, and has been pointed out by established philosophers such as Elliott Sober. A certain observation being improbable under a hypothesis does nothing by itself to discount that hypothesis. Evidence is fundamentally comparative and one must also show the further step that the observation is more probable under a plausible, alternative hypothesis. We do this when we regard things as merely improbable coincidences and not anything more when the alternative hypothesis seems even more implausible than the coincidence.

My answer to this question is relevant.

The everyday reasoning pattern that is best fit to the NHST is that outcome of criminal trials. In most common law jurisdictions, because of the legal burden of proof, finding someone "not guilty" does generally not mean that it has been proved that someone did not commit a crime, but rather that there is not enough evidence to say that the definately did commit the crime.
Thats not to say that a criminal trial cannot accumulate enough evidence to prove someone is innocent in all likelihood, but simply that the court is not interested in that determination. A court is mostly interested in only convicting people they are absolutely sure about, not in being absolutely sure they don't let guilty people go (at least the philosophically ideal court anyway).
This is different to the case of the null hypothesis in the case of testing someone for a disease. Here you want to be sure someone doesn't have a disease before you decide not to treat them, and its better to treat them that not if you are not sure.

"not rejecting the null hypothesis is never considered as evidence for the null hypothesis" - this, IMHO, is not a true statement.  It is, however, the case that "not rejecting the null hypothesis is not ALWAYS evidence for the null hypothesis." So, when one tries to use "fail to reject == evidence to accept" reasoning in arbitrary NHST contexts, one is liable to find oneself in hot water.  OTOH, when one applies this reasoning in specific contexts to which it is applicable, then this is fine.
As a simple example, suppose that I claim that "medicine X results in at least a 50% decrease in prevalence of disease Y".  Well, one can gather data in an attempt to provide evidence to reject a >50% claim, or one can gather data in an attempt to provide evidence to reject a <50% claim.  The data gathered is the same in either case.  Note that rejecting >50% is equivalent to ACCEPTing <50%, but FAILING TO REJECT <50% is NOT the same as ACCEPTing <50%, and, indeed, the math in these two cases is different and will give different results.  This means that you can set up the experiment to provide evidence FOR a particular position, but you have to decide to do so, and the mathematics may be more difficult to do this in arbitrary scenarios.

You are correct. Significance testing is actually based on an outright fallacy, and has been pointed out by established philosophers such as Elliott Sober. A certain observation being improbable under a hypothesis does nothing by itself to discount that hypothesis, even if this is the null hypothesis.
Evidence is fundamentally comparative and one must also show the further step that the observation is more probable under a plausible, alternative hypothesis. We sometimes don’t have this step when we regard things as merely improbable coincidences and not anything more when the alternative hypothesis seems even more implausible than the coincidence. For example, me having a dream that I’ll meet someone tomorrow and have it happen may be very improbable but the alternative hypothesis of my dream literally causing the world to come about the way it was portrayed in my dream may be even more implausible, thus suggesting that it was merely a coincidence.
In science, this alternative hypothesis is prima facie plausible enough (for the most part) such that we don’t need to implement the further step I just mentioned. If it seemed too implausible, we would likely not be testing it in the first place. As such, it is purely a matter of convenience that significance testing is “good enough” for our purposes even if it is based on a fallacy.
See Sober’s paper here that goes into more detail on this: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/simplicity/sober1999.pdf

To the downvoter: explain what exactly is wrong in this answer or admit that your downvote is based on nothing except hot air. I’m not sure why this seems to be a repeated theme sometimes for this site

I upvoted because I don't think this answer warrants a downvote. As someone who regularly uses NHST (in addition to Bayesian inference, likelihood-ratio-based inference, and machine learning) you cannot take NHST as some kind of deep epistemological framework. It's roots from Fisher are very pragmatic: "If you think some effect E exists, you should be able differentiate it from noise to a suitable degree of confidence."

Philosophically, there are a lot of background assumptions that NHST makes about what is being studied, and indeed it is a bit arbitrary what we consider "significant". The bigger issue is filedrawer censoring, p-hacking, and poor study design.

@Syed I must say that without reading the article, it is not clear how your answer relates to the OP. You argue that "A certain observation being improbable under a hypothesis does nothing by itself to discount that hypothesis", basically casting doubt on NHST ability just by itself to reject the null hypothesis. My query regarded the inability of NHST to accept the null hypothesis.

@Sam in that case, an observation would be more probable under the null hypothesis. But by the same error I mentioned, this tells you nothing by itself whether you should accept the null hypothesis. You must always compare and ask whether that observation is more or less probable than the alternative hypothesis before making that conclusion
